# Draw a line between two points having smallest distance in them in image Python openCV PIL

Tags: opencv, matplotlib, image-processing, python-3.5

I have an cropped image as below which actually denotes number 2

[image: chopped '2.png']

However the image is cropped such that the left part is slightly chopped off. To repair this my logic is i would be connecting two end points having the minimum distance between them/ have minimum white area between them to form something like this

[image: Joined/Repaired '2.png']

How do i achieve this i do not want all end points to get connected only the two end points having minimum distance should get connected.
I don't want some thing like this

[image: Wrong Joined '2.png']

I am a novice in Image processing using openCV python. How should i go about this?

Comment: [x-y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I am not suggesting a solution, as I think it is is not a good idea to attempt such repairs.

Comment: avoid cropping like that in the first place. in case it cannot be avoided, which I doubt, you can still recognize this as a 2 without doing any visual repairs. question is what you're trying to achieve. what is your actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may find Hausdorff distance between the two contours and get the nearest points between the contours. For this particular case, I would proceed as follows

1. Invert the image
2. Get the contours
3. filter out the unwanted contours based on their size
4. find Hausdorff distance between the two contours (and the corresponding end points)
5. draw a dilated line